# Smoke partially cut out of render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation

I have a smoke simulation that appears fine in the 3D view. However, when it is rendered, a section of the smoke is cut out. The render is done in cycles with Blender version 2.78. Changing the position/angle of the camera changes the shape that is cut out. I have 2 render layers set up, and the problem is occurring on the layer titled "dust"

[image]

[image]

[image: an image of the render]

[image: another image of the render]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g05l5akrpn5uxgo/AAAOStRFK1L7fk9MsiehouGDa?dl=0) is the blend file and pictures of the problem.

Comment: Please upload your images using I.stack.imgur and your blend file to blend exchange

Comment: Please do not use dropbox to post your images. Use the built in tools on this page: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6SIUS.png. To upload a file please use: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera end property does not extend to the end of the domain. The far plane clips the domain cube.
[image: clip domain]

Increase the camera's clipping **end** property to fix this problem.
[image]